# Extract data by pages one by one using single scrapy spider

Tags: python, web, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from [goodreads.](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/19793.I_Marked_My_Calendar_For_This_Book_s_Release?page=1)

I want to crawl pages one by one using some time delay.

My spider looks like:

```
import scrapy
import unidecode
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html


class ElementSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    download_delay = 3
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.goodreads.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/19793.I_Marked_My_Calendar_For_This_Book_s_Release?page=1",
                   ]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next_page"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@id="all_votes"]/table[@class="tableList js-dataTooltip"]/tr/td[2]/div[@class="js-tooltipTrigger tooltipTrigger"]/a/@href'):
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            print full_url
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_books)

        next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            next_href = next_page[0]
            print next_href
            next_page_url = 'https://www.goodreads.com' + next_href
            request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
            yield request

    def parse_books(self, response):
        yield{
            'url': response.url,
            'title':response.xpath('//div[@id="metacol"]/h1[@class="bookTitle"]/text()').exract(),

        }
```

Please suggest what I do so can extract all pages data by running spider once.

Comment: What does your spider currently output? Please explain what you expected, if you get nothing or only parts of what you want, or if you get blocked or something else. I doubt anyone will run your spider just to see.

Comment: It gives the desired output which i want but only the start url page "https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/19793.I_Marked_My_Calendar_For_This_Book_s_Release?page=1" I want all pages data including page-2, page-3 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make changes in my code and it works. change is -

```
request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
```

should be

```
request = scrapy.Request(next_page_url, self.parse)
```

When I comment `allowed_domains = ["https://www.goodreads.com"]` It works well otherwise there is no data saved in json file.
Can anyone one explain why??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `allowed_domains` needs a better explanation in [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) but if you check the examples, the structure of the domains there should be like `domain.com`, so avoiding scheme and unnecessary subdomains (`www` is a subdomain)